# I'm confused about value type () in Swift. What is it, and how am I meant to use it?

Tags: swift, value-type

I'm trying to convert height in feet with a decimal to height in feet and inches.

I'm trying to use the .round(.down) method to get the feet, and multiply the decimal by 12 for the inches. I'm getting all kinds of errors, like so:

```
var heightInFeet: Float = 5.45
let feetRounded = heightInFeet.round(.down) // feetRounded is "type ()." What is that?
percentToNextFoot = heightInFeet - feetRounded // Error: Binary operator '-' cannot be  applied to operands of type 'Float' and '()'
```

I tried the following and got another error:

```
percentToNextFoot = heightInFeet - Float(feetRounded) // Cannot invoke initializer for type 'Float' with an argument list of type '(())'
```

I finally got it working by avoiding the .round() method, but I'm still really confused by the value type (). Can anyone explain what's going on here?:

```
var heightInFeet: Float = 5.45
var feet = Int(heightInFeet) // 5
var percentToNextFoot = heightInFeet - Float(feet) // 0.45
let heightInFeetAndInches = "\(feet)ft \(Int(percentToNextFoot * 12))in" // 5ft 5in
```

Comment: `.round(.down)` doesn't return a value. You should be using `.rounded(.down)`.

Comment: Just beware: most users world wide don't use feet and inches, and will have no idea what this means. Unless you have a specific reason to force a specific unit choice, you should use the `MeasurementFormatter` API to use the units most appropriate for your user's langauge/region.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`()` is shorthand for `void`. It means "no value is possible here".

In this example, it means that the `.round()` method does not return anything - it is a mutating function called on its receiver. So assigning its void return to a `var` causes that var's type to be inferred to be `void`. Void vars can be useful, sometimes, rarely*, but not in this case.

Methods on value types often come in pairs: a verb like `round`, and a passive verb e.g. `rounded`. The first operates directly on, and modifies, its target; the second returns a modified version of its target. For another example, see `sort()` and `sorted()` on collections, or `append(_)` and `appending(_)` on strings, etc.
(* note: `filter` is an annoying exception; it means "filtered", and there is no handy "filter in place".)

To get the effect you were going for in the first example, `rounded()` is what you want.

--

(* To answer the tangential question in your title: how would one actually use a void variable? Well, here's a way I use them sometimes:

In an object with some setup that I would like to happen sometime after `init`, but guaranteed at most once per instance, I used to use Objective-C's `dispatch_once`. That's not available in Swift, so now I'll make a lazy void member like so:

```
class Foo {
  lazy var setup: () = {
    // do some complicated stuff I couldn't do in `init` for some reason
    // this will only run once
  }()

  func doSomethingUseful() {
    _ = setup // runs the setup initializer just the first time we get here
    // do useful things that depend on setup having happened
  }
}
```

I'll leave it to the comments to judge whether we're "meant to" use such a technique. :)

Answer (score 3):

Welcome to stack overflow!

`Double` has two rounding methods:

1. [`Double.round()`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/double/2884722-round), which rounds a `Double` value by mutating it in-place. This is one you called. It doesn't return anything, which strictly speaking means it returns `Void`, a.k.a. `()`, the empty tuple.
2. [`Double.rounded()`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/double/2886778-rounded), which rounds a `Double` value by returning a new `Double`. This is the one you probably intended to call.

By calling the first, and trying to assign the value to a variable, you end up with a variable of type `Void`, whose value is `()`.

This is a common Swift convention: "object.foo" edits it in place. "object.fooed" returns a mutated copy.

That said, in your case, I would recommend doing this using the existing `Measurement` API:

```
import Foundation

extension Measurement where UnitType == UnitLength {
    func toFeetAndInches() -> (feet: Measurement<UnitLength>, inches: Measurement<UnitLength>) {
        let numberOfWholeFeet = self.converted(to: .feet).value.rounded(.towardZero)

        return (
            feet: Measurement(value: numberOfWholeFeet, unit: UnitLength.feet),
            inches: Measurement(value: self.value - numberOfWholeFeet, unit: UnitLength.feet).converted(to: .inches)
        )
    }
}


let heightInFeet = Measurement(value: 5.5, unit: UnitLength.feet)
let (feet, inches) = heightInFeet.toFeetAndInches()

let mf = MeasurementFormatter()
mf.unitOptions = .providedUnit // force the use of feet/inches, rather than the unit appropriate for the user's locale.
mf.unitStyle = .medium
print(mf.string(for: feet)!, mf.string(for: inches)!) // => "5 ft. 6 in."
```

Answer (score 2):

If you look at the reference for the round function of Float type, you will see that it returns nothing. It just mutate the float you called this method on.

You can do

```
var feetRounded = heightInFeet                  
feetRounded.round(.down)
```

Answer (score 1):

Please take a look at the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/float/2298951-round). The method

```
mutating func round(_ rule: FloatingPointRoundingRule)
```

has no return value (aka `Void` aka `()`)

If you need a result you have to use [rounded(_:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/float/2885638-rounded) which has a return value

```
func rounded(_ rule: FloatingPointRoundingRule) -> Float
```

Answer (score 1):

`round` changes the value *in place*; you use it like this:

```
var heightInFeet: Float = 5.45
heightInFeet.round(.down)
```

You notice that no value is returned; there is no `=` in the second line. We do not need to set anything *to* the result of the `round` call, because it has no result.

If, as in your code, you accidentally *do* capture the "result", it is expressed as type `()`. So `()` is *the "result" type of a method call that has no result.*

When we accidentally write this:

```
var heightInFeet: Float = 5.45
let x = heightInFeet.round(.down)
```

we get this error: "Constant 'x' inferred to have type '()', which may be unexpected." That is just a fancy way of saying, "You've taken a method call that has no result and captured its 'result'. You probably didn't mean to do that!" And indeed, you didn't.